# checking for blank strings in list

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list as follows:

```
token = [('ACEM', 0, 5), ('(', 6, 7), ('France', 7, 13), (')', 13, 14), ('fired', 15, 20)] 
        [('ACOEM', 0, 5), ('(', 6, 7), ('France', 7, 13), (')', 13, 14), ('fired', 15, 20)] 
        [('', 0, 5), ('(', 6, 7), ('', 7, 13), (')', 13, 14), (')', 15, 20)]
        [('AWS, 0, 3), ('fired', 4, 9), ('Minnie', 10, 16), ('Pearl', 17, 22)]
```

This list contains a new list for each row. I then create a new list as follows:

```
words = []
for word in token:
    if word in string.punctuation:
        continue
    else:
        words.append(word)
```

This returns the list as :

```
words = ['ACOEM', 'France', 'fired', 'Chen', 'Kaige']
        ['ACOEM', 'France', 'fired',]
        ['', '', '', '']
        ['AWS', 'fired', 'Minnie', 'Pearl']
```

I then want to identify the line:

```
            ['', '', '', '']
```

and once identified do something else. What is the best way to do this?

My attempt was

```
from tokenize import tokenize,

for row in list:
    tokens = tokenize(row)
    for word in tokens:
        empty_string = ' ' 
        if word in string.punctuation:   
             empty_string = empty_string + ' '
        else:
             empy_string = empty_string + word
        if empty_string = ' '
             print(row)
```

Comment: Your lists are not valid Python syntax.

Comment: `len(word) == 0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use `filter` or `any` for this!

```py
>>> list(filter(None, ['', '', '', '']))
[]
>>> list(filter(None, ['', '', 'foo', '']))
['foo']
```

```py
>>> any(['', '', '', ''])
False
>>> any(['', '', '', 'foo'])
True
```